# After installing system update I can't login to my user

Tags: updates, login-screen

At the login screen, I type my password, then hit enter and I see a quick black screen with some text, as if something crashed, and it goes back to the login screen..

Help?

Comment: Please post the text displayed on the screen after you pressed the enter key.

Comment: There are many similar question on AU. Many with different reasons and solutions. Try taking a look at these other questions.http://askubuntu.com/search?q=login+loop

Answer (score 0):

Can you try **(Control+Alt F1)** to get to the console. Can you log in in?

If you can then something is broken with the Desktop or the Desktop Startup. You can try **sudo apt-get upgrade** to see if there are any updates.

you can also try **tail -200 /var/log/syslog** and see if you spot any errors in the file.

You can reboot your system using this command **sudo reboot**

This is something Quick to try, and not a solution.

to get out from Console Mode do **(Control+Alt F7)**